# How can I calculate with Inputs from Kivy (Python)

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently working on a program with Kivy and Python that solves quadratic equations. Because the user has to enter his quadratic function or the values ​​of the variables, I wanted to ask how exactly this works with Kivy and Python.
In Python it works with `a = float(input(print("Your a: ")))`.
But how do I save an input as a variable in the form "float" so that I can calculate with it?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `class`, for example: `self.a = float(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are asking for. To save an input as a float in a variable, just do `a = float(input("Your a: "))`, and then to calculate with that you can do `x = a + 89`, or `print(a**2)`. Hope I solved your question.